# How can I get a transparent artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I want to make a text effect and for that I want a transparent background. My question arises from here; how do I get a transparent background? I am using 
Illustrator CC.

Comment: Hi user42843, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The background **is**  transparent. It is just emulating paper so you can not see it. A block of white is different from the white background.

You can enable Photoshop like transparency grid by choosing **View → Show transparency grid** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>). On top of that make sure: `save for web`  has **transparency** enabled. The transparency grid is just a view option, the white background *is still transparent*, transparency grid or not. (one learns quite quickly to appraise the transparency even without the grid, which can be distracting)

Comment: This is a naive interpretation of the question. But its hard to tell there might not be enough info. If this didn't answer your intended question then *edit your question*.

Comment: This is a problem. I need to draw white text on transparent background. But I don't see text because everything is white... But thanks, your answer helped

Answer (score 6):

The background already exists as transparent. If you're trying to export for Web and getting a white background then you may be using a image type in the export that doesn't support transparencies. PNG or Gif will fix this.

It's hard to tell what you're asking for.

Answer (score 6):

Its 2019 and now a things are a bit different. You need to set the Transparency mode in AI even when exporting to PNG.

[image]

Notice the tiny Gear icon on the right. This is often missed.

Then[image]

Then finally you can set the Transparent bacgkground mode.

Then [image]

Comment: Of course ... the tiny gear-icon!  (?!!!)  It has nothing to do with 'Android' or 'iOS', naturally, despite being visually grouped with these.  Bad Adobe - a UX fail.

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the Adobe Illustrator menu bar choose "view" scroll down to "show transparent grid" and select it.

Additionally you can use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: welcome to GD.SE. Your answer doesn't add anything new

Comment: Indeed. Downvoted...